# How to make a material transparent but not its texture (Blender Render)

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

[image: Texture]
The title pretty much sums it up.

I am modelling a rubber ball. For the texture there is a png file with transparent spots without color and some wavy shapes.

Now when giving the material transparency and setting it down, it will make the texture transparent too.

The texture is too complex or I would just make another material and assign it only to the faces where the color is. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the texture tab, scroll down to *Influence* section and enable *Alpha*.

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I meant! Sorry for the other comment, I was confused.